# APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE in AWS RDS Oracle Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle-apex, amazon-rds

I am trying to install APEX on my AWS Oracle 12 RDS Instance. In order to achieve this, I am following these instructions : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.Options.APEX.HTML

However, I got stucked in step 7:

Step 7:

> You must set a password for the APEX admin user. To do this, use
> SQL*Plus to connect to your DB instance as the master user, and then
> issue the following commands:
>
> grant APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE to master;
>
> @/home/apexuser/apex/apxchpwd.sql
>
> Replace master with your master user name. When the apxchpwd.sql
> script prompts you, type a new admin password

When I log into my my RDS Instance with my master user and execute this:

```
grant APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE to [mymasteruser];
```

I received this error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01924: role 'APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE' not granted or does not exist
```

Can you please help me to solve this?

**Edit 12/09/2017.**

Using this post/answer:

```
https://serverfault.com/questions/276541/how-do-you-recover-you-rds-master-user-username
```

I understand my master user is shown in the following image. As I know, in RDS instance i have no access to sys or system user, so this is the only user i can use.

[image]

Many thanks

**Edit 20/09/2017.**

I applied Alex solution, and it works!!. However, some issues to comment:

The tutorial was changed, in fact the url changed, now is

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.Options.APEX.html  (the last "html" was in uppercase before)

but is not reliable now, there are some points that should be fixed, e.g. it says now that RDS support Oracle APEX version 5.1.2, i tried with this versión and I got this error:

[image]

Also, some directories dont match with the previos step ....

So, I used the versión that the tutorial originally says : Oracle APEX version 4.2.6.v1

I had to execute both statements :

```
EXEC rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_apex_admin_role; 
grant APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE to [master];
```

Then i could execute the apxchpwd.sql script successfully!!.

But, unfortunately, when I accessed to my apex home page and tried to create a new workspace "ws_prueba", I receive this error (Im trying to create it with my apex admin user):

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Who are you logging in as to execute this statement?

Comment: This should return a record: select * from dba_roles 
where role = 'APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE';

Comment: I'm loggin as master user to execute the grant statement. When I execute your select statement. it returns the record of the APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE. (at least it does exist).

Comment: Great that exists, but whoever your "master user" is, it needs admin_option on that role: select * from dba_role_privs where granted_role = 'APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE'

Comment: Yes, it seems it has. I execute this select : GRANTEE/GRANTED_ROLE/ADMIN_OPTION/DELEGATE_OPTION/DEFAULT_ROLE/COMMON
SYS/APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE/YES/NO/YES/YES

Comment: That makes no sense, and I still have no idea what user is attempting to execute the grant.

Comment: For me neither :(. I edited my post showing my masteruser.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your latest issue? I'm also having this problem.

Comment: Not yet. For my purposes I figured out using Oracle 11 XE. I didnt get the solution for Oracle 12c yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
EXEC rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_apex_admin_role;
```

instead. I have a case open on this with AWS and just asked them to update the documentation page.

Comment: Many Thanks. It worked!. But I got a new error. I edited my post.